# 503 Service Unavailable The server is temporarily busy, try again later! error after login

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm using Magento CE 1.9.3.8 (just upgraded to it from 1.9.2.4)
The issue I'm facing is home page, category page and product details page shows "503 Service Unavailable. The server is temporarily busy, try again later!" error after user logs in.
If user is not logged in, all the pages are accessible but once he logs in, the above mentioned issue occurs on mentioned pages.
There is no maintenance file present in the root.

[image]

Comment: did you check error log? please paste error log here.

Comment: There is nothing found in system.log OR exception.log
server logs are just saying:
[17-Apr-2018 15:10:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SCRIPT_NAME in /home/machineparts/public_html/cron.php on line 40
[17-Apr-2018 15:10:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SCRIPT_FILENAME in /home/machineparts/public_html/cron.php on line 41